# match the image src with new one if match replace the whole img tag

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have tried the above code... but it not working. i just want to change the whole `<img>` tag with new `src` and `class`.. but i down know
what attribute added into the `<img>` tag... my validation are only
if `img` `src` is matched then replace the whole `<img>` tag with new one...

```
$match="abc.jpg";    
$url ="<img class='descimg' src='111'>";

preg_replace('/<img[^>]*?src=\"'.preg_quote($match).'"',$url,$html);
```

pls help me

thank you

Comment: your [^]* will gobble up the whole of "class='descimg' src='111'>" and so you won't get a match on src

Comment: Use DOMDocument and XPath - https://ideone.com/Pegvwm

Answer (score 0):

Further to me comment the following preg_replace line should work better. I can't actually tell from your description exactly what you are trying to do. If you included your expected output I will improve my answer as required to fit.

```
preg_replace('/<img[ ]+src=\"'.preg_quote($match).'"',$url,$html);
```

I also note that $match does not appear in the your original string and so it is odd that it is part of the regular expression?